# If multiple classes have a static variable in common, are they shared (within the same scope?)

Tags: c++, static, static-members

I have the following example code:

```
class A {
    public:
        static int a;
};
int A::a = 0;

class B {
    public:
        static A a1;
};
A B::a1;

class C {
    public:
        static A a1;
};
A C::a1;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    C::a1.a++;
    B::a1.a++;
    std::cout << B::a1.a << " " << C::a1.a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Class B and C have class A as a static member variable.

I expected the program to print "1 1", however it prints "2 2".

If multiple classes have a static variable in common, are they shared (within the same scope?)

Comment: It might be eye-opening to add objects `B b1,b2` and `C c1,c2, c3`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) belong to class, it has nothing to do with objects.

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the class: they are independent objects with static storage duration or regular functions defined in namespace scope, only once in the program.

For your code, there's only one `A::a`, which is independent of `B::a1` and `C::a1` (which are objects of class `A`). So both `B::a1.a` and `C::a1.a` refer to `A::a`.

Answer (score 19):

You're not looking at multiple classes here. Both `B::a1` and `C::a1` are of type `A`. And `A` has a static variable `a`, that you accessed twice. If you also wrote `A::a++`, your program would have printed `3 3`

To modify your example slightly:

```
struct A
{
    static int a;
    int b;
};
int A::a;

struct B
{
    static A a1;
};
A B::a1{0};

struct C
{
    static A a2;
};
A C::a2{0};
```

and the user code:

```
B::a1.a = 1; // A's static variable changed
B::a1.b = 2; // B's A's b changed to 2
cout << B::a1.a << ",  " << B::a1.b << endl;
cout << C::a2.a << ",  " << C::a2.b << endl;
```

It will print:

```
1, 2
1, 0
```

That's because all `A`s share `a`, but all `A`s have their own `b`. And both `C` and `B` have their own `A` (that they respectively share between objects of their type)

Answer (score 0):

B and C both have static instances of A, these are seperate instances of A and would have different seperate instances of it's members as well. However, A::a is a static variable that is shared between all instances of A so:

&B::a1 != &C::a1 (the two a1 are seperate)

but

&B::a1.a == &C::a1.a (i.e. all A::a are the same, no matter the 'enclosing' instance of A)